# AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'Layer._initializer_tracker.<locals>.<lambda>'

Tags: python, keras, pickle

I am trying to save the neural network and use it elsewhere but this error shows up every time I compile.
Though the pkl file is created

[image: Screenshot of the error]
Is this a major error or is this version related?

Will this error impact my other models as well or is it related to neural networks specifically

Comment: As you can [read in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled), lambda functions can't be pickled. If it's possible, redefine the functions you use in the model with `def`.